# Duplicate ranges in C# Word Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a word template where some paragraphs needs to be duplicated programmitacaly. I tried to use range.duplicate, but it wouldn't do the job.

Now, i have this code:

```
        document.Bookmarks["Experience"].Select();
        Word.Range range = application.Selection.Range;

        range.Copy();
        range.Paste();
```

But it doesn't insert anything to the documentum. Can you please help me?

Comment: It replaces the existing selection with the copied selection.  So sure, no net change that you could ever see.  From the Range.Paste() documentation: "If you don't want to replace the contents of the range, use the Collapse method before using this method.".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the two ranges are identical. It's like when you're working in the document using the mouse or keyboard: If you have a selection and paste, what you paste will replace what was selected. In order to have the one follow the other you first need to press the right-arrow key or click somewhere.

So you need to specify a second Range (such as the end of the document or another bookmark), or as suggested in @HansPassant comment, "collapse" the Range (like pressing an arrow key).

Another thing to keep in mind is that you shouldn't use the Clipboard, if at all possible. The alternative in Word is to use `FormattedRange` to transfer foramtted content. The sample code below shows both variations.

```
    //Possibility 1:
    Word.Range rangeSource = document.Bookmarks["Experience"].Range;
    Word.Range rangeTarget = rangeSource.Duplicate();
    rngTarget.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
    rngTarget.FormattedText = rngSource.FormattedText;

    //Possibility 2:    
    Word.Range rangeSource = document.Bookmarks["Experience"].Range;
    rangeSource.Copy();
    rngSource.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
    rangeSource.Paste();
```